# XCode 5 Facebook SDK Error

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, xcode5

I downloaded Facebook SDK from Apple Developer Site and it installed in the default location (Documents folder). When running my application, I am getting the error "PBXCp Error" as follows:

/Users/.../Downloads/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/Resources/FacebookSDKResources.bundle: No such file or directory

Also, framework search paths has no value entries in it and is still on default xCode settings.

How can I resolve this problem to run the application? (New to xCode)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Xcode is trying to access the SDK in your `~/Downloads` directory. Assuming the Facebook SDK installed in your `~/Documents` directory, you may need to remove the framework from your project and re-add it from `~/Documents`.